SQL math formula showing different value vs manually entering in calculator
I'm trying to run a query with this math formula converting inches to cubic feet. When I key in the data on a calculator the value is different than what the SQL shows.
Can anyone advise on why the discrepancy in numbers? 24.82222 is the correct number.
24 (cases) / 24 (quantity per layer on pallet) * 16.34 (case height) + 6 (pallet height) * 48 (pallet length) * 40 (pallet width) / 1728 (inches to cubic feet) = X
SELECT 24 / 24 * 16.34 +6 * 48 * 40 / 1728 FROM table

The SQL return value shows 23.00666... Correct should be 24.8222
The exact query I am running
SELECT ROUND(a.std_qty / 
            (SELECT item_qty_bkd_qty_per_lay 
               FROM m_item_d1 b 
               WHERE a.comp_code=b.comp_code and a.cust_code=b.cust_code and a.invt_lev1=b.item_code and b.item_qty_bkd_lev_num=1) 
            * 
            (SELECT item_qty_bkd_hgt 
               FROM m_item_d1 b 
               WHERE a.comp_code=b.comp_code and a.cust_code=b.cust_code and a.invt_lev1=b.item_code and b.item_qty_bkd_lev_num=2) 
            + 6 * 48 * 40 / 1728,2) as CUBIC_FT
FROM c_cart_d a
.....

THANKS in advance!

Break the calculation into smaller steps and identify where the values deviate

Put your formula into https://www.mathsisfun.com/algebra/operations-order-calculator.html  to see if you are performing it in the right order on the calculator.

When I key your formula into a calculator, it also gives me 23.006666. You are adding just the height of a layer to the pallet volume and not the layer volume.

Is this Oracle 11g as your profile's "top tags" would currently suggest?  Please take a look at Oracle's Precedence Example, which explains why 1+2*3 is 7 and not 9.

Note that some dbms's do integer division. https://calcitfast.com/integer-division

@pilcrow  Thank you for the link.  I am using oracle 11g. I override the precedence by using parenthesis.

Here is the order of operations SQL is using:
Multiply or Divide before you Add or Subtract.
Otherwise just go left to right.
24÷24×16.34+(6×48×40)÷1728
1×16.34+(6×48×40)÷1728
16.34+(6×48×40)÷1728
16.34+(288×40)÷1728
16.34+11520÷1728
16.34+6.666666666666667
23.006666666666668


Depending on dbms. Integer division, which is pretty common, makes 11520÷1728 = 6.

Unless you're programming in APL, we don't use ÷ for division, we use /. In the font SO uses, it's hard to distinguish from +. And multiplication is *.

Thank you for everyones input. It helped me understand better how the SQL was calculating.
I was able to resolve my issue with overriding precedence using parenthesis as shown below.
SELECT (24/24*16.34+6) * 48 * 40 / 1728 as CUBIC_FT 
FROM ...

